# Issue dereferencing type void**

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I have an array of pointers to pointers:

```
void ** buckets.
```

Each of these pointers point to some blob of memory, which contains a pointer to another blob of memory.

I am trying to get at one of the pointers which point to some blob of memory like this:

```
void *cell = cm->buckets[0] // for the first blob it is pointing to.
```

However, it is giving me a segfault and the gdb is not very useful. Why is this happening and what is the proper way of handling this case?

Comment: Is `cm` a struct or a class?  Can you include the code that sets `cm`?

Comment: and have `buckets` been initialized?

Comment: `Why is this happening and what is the proper way of handling this case?` How can anybody diagnose your problem with the very sparse information given?

Comment: @FiddlingBits I'm genuinely curious - is there any case other than protected memory access which can cause segfaults? Of course, I'm assuming no messing around with memory allocators, etc.

Comment: You likely haven't allocated these blobs of memory, or haven't stored the pointers to the allocated memory correctly.

Comment: @metacubed: Of course you can diagnose that something is wrong with the `buckets` pointer, but we can only guess what might be the cause of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the address value stored in `buckets`. Most likely, it has not been initialized (using `new`, `malloc`, etc.) and the address inside `buckets` is some random protected mem address.

`buckets[0]` is equivalent to `*buckets` or dereferencing the value inside `buckets`. So the system tries to access the contents of this protected address causing a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible places that may be generating this fault in your example code: `cm` and `buckets`. In GDB, before you execute this line, first check `cm` to make sure it is pointing where you expect it to. If so, make sure `buckets` is pointing to a reasonable location.